# Passar o parâmetro $rfprod ao clicar na linha para um program PHP (Método POST)

Tags: php, javascript

```
<div id="posiciona">
    <table id="mostra_prod" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#000000">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <td align="right" bgcolor="#0a0a96">Aplicação</td>
           <td align="left"  bgcolor="#0a0a96">Referência</td> 
         </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
        $i=0;         
        while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_pd)) { 
            $rfprod  = $row['pro_referencia_produto'];
            $idref[] = $rfprod;  
            $i++;  
            $approd  = $row['pro_aplicacao_produto'];
            ?><tr><?php 
            echo "<td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1; font-size:14px;'>".$approd."</td>";
            echo "<td style='color: #ffffff; font-size:11px; padding-top: 5px;'>".$rfprod."</td>";
            ?></tr><?php 
       }
       ?>   
        </tbody>      
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: Tabela de Produtos]

Comment: Sua questão não ficou muito clara. Tenta formular melhor a pergunta (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Caro Linhares, Ok! Ao selecionar a linha no evento Onclick, eu preciso enviar pelo POST, o código de referencia do item para o outro programa em PHP, que mostrará todas as imagens desse item. Agradecido...!

Comment: Mas porque via POST? Alguma razão em especial? Por GET fica muito mais simples, veja:  echo "<td style='color: #ffffff; font-size:11px; padding-top: 5px;'><?php echo('<a href="PAGINA_DESTINO.php?ref='.$rfprod.'">'.$rfprod.'</a>');?></td>

Comment: Leo, a sintaxe do comando,não está correta! ;‌​?></td>  Nesse ponto do comando está mostrando caracteres especiais, dois pontos vermelho  antes do final de fechamento do php. No final do comando eu inseri o ; A msg de erro - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catalog2' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\tutoriais\catalog000.php on line 121

Comment: Leo, Como ficará o comando de GET no programa catalog2.php ?

Comment: Resolvido Leo !   echo "<td align=right style='font-size:15px'>
            <a href=catalog02.php?referencia=$rfprod style='color: #cfcfd1; text-decoration: none;'>$approd</a></td>";  
    
            echo "<td style='font-size:11px; padding-top: 5px;'>
            <a href=catalog02.php?referencia=$rfprod style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;'>$rfprod</a></td>";

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer que, quando o usuário clique no item, o código de referência dele seja enviado por POST. Beleza. 
Primeiro vou fazer umas modificações no seu código atual:

```
<div id="posiciona">
    <table id="mostra_prod" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#000000">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <td align="right" bgcolor="#0a0a96">Aplicação</td>
           <td align="left"  bgcolor="#0a0a96">Referência</td> 
         </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
        $i=0;         
        while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_pd)) { 
            $rfprod  = $row['pro_referencia_produto'];
            $idref[] = $rfprod;  
            $i++;  
            $approd  = $row['pro_aplicacao_produto'];
            ?><tr id="item"><?php 
            echo "<td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1; font-size:14px;'>".$approd."</td>";
            echo "<td style='color: #ffffff; font-size:11px; padding-top: 5px;' id='referencia-item'>".$rfprod."</td>";
            ?></tr><?php 
       }
       ?>   
        </tbody>      
    </table>
</div>
```

O que eu fiz: coloquei um id no "tr" pai para que eu pudesse selecioná-lo mais facilmente, assim como no "td" da referência.
Agora vamos para a parte do js (jquery):

```
   $(function(){
        $("#item").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "referencia.php",
    type: post,
    data: ({referencia: $(this).find('#referencia-item').text()}),
    success: function(resposta){
    alert(resposta);
    }
    });
    });
    });
```

E crie um arquivo chamado "referencia.php"
Faça seu php nele! 
Exemplo:

```
<?php
$referencia = $_POST['referencia'];
echo "O código de referência do produto clicado é ".$referencia;
?>
```

Espero que entenda.
Desculpe a má formatação, estou pelo celular!

Comment: Caro VME, Inseri o seu código, mas não deu certo...! Ao clicar na linha, não houve a chamada para o outro programa...!

Comment: Haveria possibilidade de enviar o código inteiro pra ti? Abro um outro registro de atendimento?

Comment: Você trocou para o primeiro código, como citei?

Comment: Se sim, aperte a linha e depois vá no console do seu navegador e informe os erros, caso presentes

Comment: Alterei conforme sua edição..! A mensagem do Console .....         
    Uncaught ReferenceError: post is not defined
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (catalog00.php:135)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.dispatch (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.u (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)                                             A linha 135 é ; url: "catalog02.php",